# Difference between roaring 20s and raging 20s?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

One article [A recession in America by 2024 looks likely](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/06/02/a-recession-in-america-by-2024-looks-likely) from The Economist has a subtitle named:

> From the roaring to the raging 2020s

From Google's online Dictionary(which is from Oxford):

- roaring means: *making or uttering a loud, deep, or harsh prolonged sound*
- raging means: *showing violent uncontrollable anger.*

Although their meanings differ, they both seem to imply something terrible.
"Roaring 20s" is commonly used phrase, but here "raging 2020s" is newly invented(they are trying to imply bearish). What is the logic here?

Comment: The "Roaring 20s" were the 1920s.

Comment: The 'Roaring 20s' is a fixed phrase; the reason it was/is so called can easily be found in say [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaring_Twenties). The 'raging 2020s' is not a fixed phrase (though perhaps a group has chosen it as a name); it is a recent invention, modelling of course on the original. As to why the Economist uses the term: doubtless their article will explain. But it's as yet a non-standard usage.

Comment: The Economist prides itself on using unusual usages. Especially in titles. Arnold Zwicky believes there is no linguistic depth they will not plumb to make a joke, a pun, an allusion, or a political comment -- ideally, all at once.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Edited.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What I see in the roaring 20s wiki page is only a summary of what 20s looks like. This page [here](https://historydaily.org/why-is-it-called-the-roaring-20s) might explain a bit, since 20s was "roaring with changes".

Comment: The Economist subtitle might have something to do with  a 2021 book by Alex Ross entitled [*The Raging 2020s*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/56347315-the-raging-2020s)

Comment: When I came to know about [roaring boys](https://www.lexico.com/definition/roaring_boy), particularly in Irish usage where the term seems to have persisted longer than in English usage, I have always assumed that the term Roaring Twenties was derived from, or related to, Roaring Boys. The Roaring Twenties were, of course, a period of post war hedonism and economic confidence in the USA following the end of WW1. The 2020s are almost the exact opposite for various reasons.

Comment: ' ...  In France, the decade was known as the années folles ("crazy years"), emphasizing the era's social, artistic and cultural **dynamism**. Jazz blossomed, the flapper redefined the modern look for British and American women .... [emphasis mine]. So exuberant, risk-taking, progressive.  Collins includes for 'roaring' _very active or successful_. Another dictionary has _booming_.

Comment: ELU really can't answer as to why some author chose a particular word, we can only guess. 'raging' was probably chosen because it is short, catchy, sort of isn't totally 
 different from roaring ('rapids' can 'roar' or 'rage'?) and starts with 'r'.

Comment: The raging twenties sound a lot angrier.

Comment: Roaring and raging are both loud (and both start with R); a crowd can roar in excitement or approval, a roaring fire in the hearth is good, the roaring 20s were fun; while raging usually denotes disapproval. However raging can be good ("all the rage", passion or fervor, [sense 2 here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rage), rager=party), and roaring can be bad. Some bad things, like storms, can roar or rage. That ambiguity is probably what makes it seem clever to the Economist journalists. This is more in the realm of literary criticism than English usage.